My [recommendation] is to remove this tag
I recently encountered the recommendation tag. No tag description, 19 questions. This is a classic "Meta tag". Topic-wise, the questions have little in common with each other, and many are off-topic recommendation questions.
Can we remove this tag?

Yes, IMO we should remove it. Let's leave this for a bit for any contrary views but if there are none I think you or anyone could just start removing it, as there are only 19 instances and it won't leave any orphan (completely untagged) questions.
EDIT: it should be gone now. I closed a couple of the really obvious off-topic ones but didn't spend much time on that.
I can't easily stop the tag coming back but this question should be a good reference to support immediately removing it if it does.
